# Exporting a Json array after fetching from database React

Tags: json, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb

Right now, I'm trying to get data from DynamoDB database with below code.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        await (API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listItemTables, {limit: 18})).then(e => {
            setProducts(e.data.listItemTables.items);

        }).catch(e => {console.log("Failed to retrieve data");}));

    };
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

After fetch data from database, data will store as a JSON array in product like below.

```
{
"title": "Apple iPhone 7 Plus 32 GB",
"category": "phone",
"images": ["https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/18/280-413/9801258663986.jpg?v1"],
"brand": "apple",
"condition": "Used",
"price": 800,
"id": 0,
"description": "Apple"
},....
```

So, is there anyway that I can export data to use for others components like below?

```
export const product =[{
 "title": "Apple iPhone 7 Plus 32 GB",
 "category": "phone",
 "images": ["https://productimages.hepsiburada.net/s/18/280-413/9801258663986.jpg?v1"],
 "brand": "apple",
 "condition": "Used",
 "price": 800,
 "id": 0,
 "description": "Apple"
 }];
```

please let me know if you don't understand anywhere.

Comment: You can use Redux

Comment: You can store the result in state and use redux to use it across the components

Comment: Thank you so much!! I used Redux and it's working great